# Query taking too long to execute in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I've written a query which should take all the rows from one table and do a subquery to a second table pulling only one value from the most recent record.  In **SQL Server** the query takes about 15 seconds to execute and the LINQ query takes close to 2 minutes.  Can someone help me with translating the SQL to LINQ, I must have done something wrong along the way.

The `SQL`:

```
SELECT  a.isrunning,
        worktype = (
                    SELECT TOP 1
                            w.worktype
                    FROM    dbo.workorder w WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   w.assetnum = a.assetnum
                    ORDER BY w.statusdate DESC
                   ),
        a.status,
        *
FROM    dbo.asset a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE   a.assetnum IN ('list', 'of', 'asset', 'numbers')
```

The `LINQ` Query:

```
(
  from a in db.assets
  let wo = (
            from w in db.workorders
            where w.assetnum == a.assetnum
            orderby w.statusdate descending
            select w).FirstOrDefault()
   where aliasStrings.Contains(a.assetnum)
   select new AssetWithWorkType {
      ...
   }
);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: Add index on foreign key `assetnum`, and another one on `w.statusdate`

Comment: also do you really need every column from your dbo.asset table? you should only return columns you will be using.

Comment: Okay, sorry everyone, I've edited the question.  Originally it was taking about 2 minutes on both sides (SQL Server and LINQ).  I had changed some things and thought it was the same, but it looks like SQL Server is down to ~15 seconds now while the LINQ version stays at ~2 minutes.  I guess now the question is just, what is different in my LINQ than my SQL.

Comment: Without being able to see what columns you are selecting for your final object, the only differences I see is that the SQL version is using `NOLOCK`, and the subquery is only selecting one column in SQL but the entire row in LINQ.

Comment: For the LINQ version, would putting the `wo` in the `select` (after the `where`) make a difference? Have you looked at the SQL your LINQ statement generates?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to have indexes on foreign keys. Also indexes that covers filtering and ordering clauses. So I suggest you to create the following 3 indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_workorder_statusdate] ON dbo.workorder(statusdate)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_workorder_assetnum] ON dbo.workorder(assetnum)
```

If `assetnum` column in `asset` table is not the primary key then additionally:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_asset_assetnum] ON dbo.asset(assetnum)
```

Comment: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_workorder] ON dbo.workorder(assetnum,statusdate,worktype)` would probably be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp table for the correlated subquery results, and then join it later. Syntax is not correct, as I dont have your table schemas or data, but the idea is the same.

```
CREATE TABLE #workTypes (worktype VARCHAR(X), assetnum VARCHAR(x))

INSERT INTO #workTypes
SELECT TOP 1 worktype, assetnum FROM dbo.workorder ORDER BY statusdate DESC

SELECT  a.isrunning,
        b.worktype, 
        a.status,
        *
FROM    dbo.asset a WITH (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN #worktypes b
      ON a.assetnum = b.assetnum
WHERE   a.assetnum IN ('list', 'of', 'asset', 'numbers')
```

Comment: OP has correlated subquery, but you are picking just one value from workorder table?

Comment: The point is to not perform the subquery at the same time as the main query. Get that recordset first, and then join it in.

Comment: if you see correlated subquery will return different worktype for different assetnum IN ('list', 'of', 'asset', 'numbers'). Your query will pick just one worktype and assign it to all rows in outer query...

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - Dont focus on the content of the query. Focus instead on the idea of splitting the query into two distinct parts to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT  a.isrunning,
        w.worktype,
        cnt = count(*)
FROM       dbo.asset a WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo workorder w WITH (NOLOCK) on w.assetnum = a.assetnum
WHERE      a.assetnum IN ('list', 'of', 'asset', 'numbers')
```

This would give you a count of worktypes for each asset and might allow the database server to optimize more efficiently.  Also consider adding indices or using a temp table as other answers have suggested.